# Auto logout on disconnect

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is there any way to clear the ASP.NET session when the system looses its connection? I guess it could be implemented using JavaScript can anyone tell me how?

Page must be automatically redirect to logout.aspx after system gets connected to internet again.

For more clarity, chat scripts shows online and offline notification. It means for example when his Gmail page is ON his contacts can see him status as green. When his page is OFF his contacts see it OFF. How this is implemented?

Comment: I guess it's server-side, so JavaScript is actually not what you want to use

Comment: What does *`when the system looses its connection`* mean? HTTP is a stateless protocol.

Comment: Are you talking about a session stored in a cookie or a session on the server? Either way JavaScript can't do this. Just have a session timeout in ASP (like 3 minutes or something).

Comment: @Darin - Unconditionally disconnected to internet.

Comment: @meutex, who? The client? And you expect your server to know that the client was *`Unconditionally disconnected to internet`*? In a stateless protocol such as HTTP is?

Comment: @tjameson- I mean a server session.

Comment: @All - I mean, when soon system is again connected to internet the session should end by redirecting to logout.aspx page.

Comment: @meutex, I would suggest you reading more in details about how the HTTP protocol works as your questions hardly make sense.

Comment: @Darin - I have never mentioned using HTTP anywhere. See the answer may be like this. Use auto post back for every 3mins. If this fails then redirect to logout page when the internet is connected back. Its possible. But you please read the question completely before commenting on it.

Comment: @meutex, ohh, sorry, then I must have misunderstood your `asp.net` tag. Could you explain what is the relation with it in this case if you are not using the HTTP protocol?

Comment: @Darin - See the question which I asked relates to ASP.NET where you can even use ascx and .cs code too in ASP.NET

Comment: @meutex, do you know what the HTTP protocol is?

Comment: @Darin - Well Darin.! I agree that I am a newbie to .NET also I don't have patience to argue with you. Leave this here.

Comment: @meutex I don't think anyone was arguing with you, just trying to figure out what you're trying to do. The way HTTP works is very relevant here. Also, it's not clear which "system" you're talking about: The server or the client? Are you trying to detect whether the server is completely down, or whether the client still has the page open in his browser window? We're trying to understand your question, but it's very difficult to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: @Jistin - For more clarity, chat scripts shows online and offline notification. It means for example when his Gmail page is ON his contacts can see him status as green. When his page is OFF his contacts see it OFF. How this is implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use session timeout in ASP.NET for disconnecting the user on inactivity for certain duration. Its usage in web.config file:

```
<system.web>
|
|
<authentication mode="Forms" />
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20"/>
|
|
</system.web>
```

HTTP is a stateless protocol as all other have said so....

I do not understand what do you mean by the `when the system looses its connection`. An ambiguous answer to the same can be: You can also edit your `global.asax` file for clearing session. You can use `Session.Abandon()` in the methods: `Session_End` and `Application_End`. A little demonstratively:

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        // Code that runs when a session ends.
    }
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Session.Abandon(); 
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just using the sessions timeout in ASP if you intend for the client to be disconnected, maybe from lack of activity.  Unless you want the session cleared if the server goes down?